# Android Quiz App Crashing while checking answer from user

Tags: java, android, xml

The problem that I encounter seems to happen checkIfRight(), I want it to get the text of when a button is clicked and then checking that text against the rightAnswers array element and if it is right then display "right" and if wrong then display "wrong" This doesn't seem to work even though I am comparing two Strings in the if statement. If anyone can help me I'd be for ever grateful.

**This is the code below for my java class:**

```
package com.example.tass.damnquizinfoapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class Categories extends AppCompatActivity {

int count = 1;
Button btn;
TextView score;
int count2 = 0;
String buttonText;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);



}


String[] quesitons =
        {
                "What was the tallest Damn as of 2017?",
                "How many people did the South Fork Dam kill in 1889?",
                "What do Damns generate?",
                "By how much percent did freshwater species decline by due to dams since 1970?",
                "Around what time was the first damn built?",
                "How many large(15m+) dams are in existence today?",
                "The average dam can be expected to cost how much?"
        };

String[] rightAnswers =
        {
                "Jinping-I",
                "2200",//right
                "Energy",//right
                "37%",
                "4000 B.C",
                "57,000",
                "A few billion dollars"
        };

String[] sampleAnswersA =
        {
                "The Sanxia",
                "2200",//right
                "Energy",//right
                "20%",
                "1280 A.D",
                "7,000",
                "Less than $20million"
        };

String[] sampleAnswersB =
        {
                "Jinping-I",//right
                "204",
                "Fish",
                "68%",
                "4000 B.C",//right
                "57,000",//right
                "More than $1 trillion"
        };

String[] sampleAnswersC =
        {
                "Guri Dam",
                "7819",
                "Water",
                "37%", //right
                "2800 B.C",
                "78,0000",
                "A few billion dollars"//right
        };



public void a1()
{

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1);
    btn.setText(sampleAnswersA[count]);



}

public void a2()
{

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2);
    btn.setText(sampleAnswersB[count]);


}

public void a3()
{

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3);
    btn.setText(sampleAnswersC[count]);
    getQuestions();


}

public void getQuestions()
{
    TextView txt;
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    txt.setText(quesitons[count]);

}


  //THIS SEEMS TO BE CAUSING ME PROBLEMS 
 public void checkIfRight()

{
    String buttonText;
    buttonText = btn.getText().toString();
    if (rightAnswers[count2].equals(buttonText))
    {
        score = findViewById(R.id.score);
        score.setText("right");
    }

    else{score.setText("wrong");}

}


public void onClick(View v)
{
    a1();
    a2();
    a3();
    checkIfRight();
    getQuestions();
    count++;
    count2++;
}
```

}

**This is the code for the XML class:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#e7e7e7"
>

 <ImageView
   android:layout_width="350dp"
   android:layout_height="450dp"
   android:src="@drawable/whitebackground"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   />

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/q1"
   android:layout_width="300dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:onClick="onClick"
   android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
   android:background="@drawable/rounded_btn"
   android:text="The Sanxia"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textStyle="bold" />

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/q2"
   android:layout_width="300dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="203dp"
   android:onClick="onClick"
   android:background="@drawable/rounded_btn"
   android:text="Jinping-I"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textStyle="bold" />


 <Button
   android:id="@+id/q3"
   android:layout_width="300dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
   android:onClick="onClick"
   android:background="@drawable/rounded_btn"
   android:text="Guri Dam"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textStyle="bold"

   />

 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/mytext"
   android:layout_width="253dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
   android:text="What was the tallest Damn as of 2017?"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:textSize="20dp"
   android:textStyle="bold" />

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/mybutton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
   android:text="NEXT"
   android:onClick="onClick"
   />


 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/score"
   android:layout_width="99dp"
   android:layout_height="130dp"
   android:layout_above="@+id/q1"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="-180dp"
   android:text="Answer:"
   android:textStyle="bold" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It crashes or doesn't work how it's intended to meaning that it doesn't output wrong or right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In check if right method
You put this line inside if
score = findViewById(R.id.score)
You made it local
So when perform the else
It will crash
That's wrong put it before if and I suggest you put all lines findviewbyid in oncreate method

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled your code and got the same error as you got, and I found that you initialized `TextView score` in if statement and it happens only user chooses `right answer` but happens in `wrong answer` so, please have a look the code below:

```
package com.example.dosto.categories;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txt;
    int count = 1;
    Button btn;
    TextView score;
    int count2 = 0;
    String buttonText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2);
        score = findViewById(R.id.score);

    }

    String[] quesitons =
            {
                    "What was the tallest Damn as of 2017?",
                    "How many people did the South Fork Dam kill in 1889?",
                    "What do Damns generate?",
                    "By how much percent did freshwater species decline by due to dams since 1970?",
                    "Around what time was the first damn built?",
                    "How many large(15m+) dams are in existence today?",
                    "The average dam can be expected to cost how much?"
            };

    String[] rightAnswers =
            {
                    "Jinping-I",
                    "2200",//right
                    "Energy",//right
                    "37%",
                    "4000 B.C",
                    "57,000",
                    "A few billion dollars"
            };

    String[] sampleAnswersA =
            {
                    "The Sanxia",
                    "2200",//right
                    "Energy",//right
                    "20%",
                    "1280 A.D",
                    "7,000",
                    "Less than $20million"
            };

    String[] sampleAnswersB =
            {
                    "Jinping-I",//right
                    "204",
                    "Fish",
                    "68%",
                    "4000 B.C",//right
                    "57,000",//right
                    "More than $1 trillion"
            };

    String[] sampleAnswersC =
            {
                    "Guri Dam",
                    "7819",
                    "Water",
                    "37%", //right
                    "2800 B.C",
                    "78,0000",
                    "A few billion dollars"//right
            };


    public void a1() {
        btn.setText(sampleAnswersA[count]);
    }

    public void a2() {
        btn.setText(sampleAnswersB[count]);
    }

    public void a3() {
        btn.setText(sampleAnswersC[count]);
        getQuestions();

    }

    public void getQuestions() {
        txt.setText(quesitons[count]);
    }

    public void checkIfRight() {
        String buttonText;
        buttonText = btn.getText().toString();
        if (rightAnswers[count2].equals(buttonText)) {
            score.setText("right");
        } else {
            score.setText("wrong");
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        a1();
        a2();
        a3();
        checkIfRight();
        getQuestions();
        count++;
        count2++;
    }
}
```

So, please look at these Runtime Exceptions.

This error comes from `checkIfRight()`:
[image]

This error comes after fixing `checkIfRight()` and it occurs in `a1()`:
[image]

Conclusion is that you need to initialize views and buttons in `onCreate()` so that you do not get any `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

Comment: Thank you so much mate! Really helped me. Thanks for the detailed solution! What a hero!